# how can I convert an Object to a string?

Tags: java, jcombobox

I want to take from a list the user's choice and convert it to a string with Jbox. How can I convert the contents to string so I can use it?

```
public class Graph extends JFrame
{
    private String temp;

    public Graph()
    { }
    public void CreateBox(String[] a)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton jButton1 = new JButton("ok");
        final JList jList1 = new JList(a);
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                Object contents = jList1.getSelectedValue();
                //System.out.println(contents);
                setChoise((String)contents);//how can i convert it to string ?
            }
        });
        JButton jButton2 = new JButton("close");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });    
        frame.add(jList1, "Center");
        frame.add(jButton1,"South");
        frame.add(jButton2,"North");
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void setChoise(String temp)
    {
        this.temp=temp;
    }

    public String getChoise()
    {
        return this.temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this not work?
`String contents = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();`

Comment: @Ascalonian That does not work.  It is not legal Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert object to string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055476/how-to-convert-object-to-string-in-java)

Comment: Hold on isn't the problem more with how the JList is declared?  Wouldn't declaring it as a `JList<String>` solve the issue all together?

Comment: @chancea : True that!! but again after that point he won't be having the object afterwards for manipulation.

Comment: @ajb How is that not legal Java?

Comment: @Ascalonian OK, I missed that there are raw generics and unchecked conversions all around.  So it's actually legal, but not recommended.  My mistake.  Changing to `JList<String>` is the best answer.

Comment: JList can not be converted to JList<String> I guess.

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq The [javax.swing.JList<E>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)  is declared with generics.. or maybe I don't understand your comment

Comment: @ajb Np! I just wanted to know what I did wrong. It is a Friday afterall ;)

Comment: @chancea no you are correct. I was looking at jdk 1.6 implementation.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to be different and explain a solution but not the one proposed of converting the `Object` to a `String`.  Rather just declare your `JList` for its proper use (which it seems is to hold `Strings`).  Just declare the list as

```
final JList<String> jList1 = new JList<String>(a);
```

and then the `getSelectedValue()` method will return a `String` not a raw `Object` allowing you to use it in methods that take in a `String`.

However as people have already noted, this will not work if you need to manipulate the list as `Objects`, so only do this if you are only using the list for `Strings`

Comment: This is the appropriate answer in his scenario. My bad, I didn't see he is passing String[].

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to implement the toString method of that object.

```
@Override public String toString() {

    return field1 + field2; //Example
  }
```

Then you can simply do

```
setChoise((ClassType)contents);
```

**EDIT:**

**Another option will be :**

Typecast the `Object` into its `class`. (In your case you are not doing it )

Say the Object is of type `City` you can simply put `City myCity = (City)contents` (Again you have to manage multiple selection)

Then call the getters of the fields you want to display. say :

```
setChoise(myCity.getName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a method called:

```
public String toString(){

    String result = "All the values inside the class u want to display";
    return result;

}
```

Now When you use `System.out.println(Graph);`

It should get the result form the `toString()` method

Comment: It should still display it with out @Override

Comment: Yes and using raw types and cryptic variable names also works. But that doesn't mean you should do that.

Comment: Every one has his own way of doing something. I just never bother overriding toString methods, since they always returned same result

Comment: I'm not sure this is right, because it's not clear to me that the questioner wants to convert a `Graph` to a `String`.  I don't see anywhere where he's trying to use `println` on a `Graph`.