# Convert a List<Object> to List String

Tags: java

```
Query  w=em.createQuery("SELECT ar.authorId.firstName,
                        count(ar) FROM Article ar
                        WHERE ar.categoryId.categoryText=:
                                                 categoryText GROUP BY ar.authorId"); 
       w.setParameter("categoryText", categoryText); 

       List list1=w.getResultList();  


       System.out.println(list1.toString());
```

Whats the wrong. i get `[[Ljava.lang.Object;@60a19573, [Ljava.lang.Object;@44a085e5]`

I want to print the query like "name:"+firtname+"Articles:"+count(ar)

Comment: cast to specific type of `List` and then implement `toString()` in that particular type

Comment: First of all it would be nice to give your colleagues a hint what the objects are: hibernate???

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert object to string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055476/how-to-convert-object-to-string-in-java)

Comment: By default the toString method get the class names. You should have a method like myList.Cast<String>().ToList(), that is how we do in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're getting back in your query is a `List<Object[]>` which is expected as per the spec.  The first element in your array is the string `ar.authorId.firstName` and the second is a `Long` representing `count(ar)`

A `String.format` should work here for you:

```
for(Object[] objs : list1) {
    System.out.println(String.format("name %s articles %s",objs[0],objs[1]);
}
```

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer @palios7 please do accept it :-)

Answer (score 4):

Implement `toString()` in that particular type `SomeType`

Comment: The generic cast isn't necessary just for nice output; `toString()` is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: You could make it a little clearer that the last line of your answer is the only one that matters.  If it were me, I'd just delete the first six lines.

Comment: What is `SomeType` here?

Comment: the object model type class that you are querying from DB

Comment: please could you be more specific how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`for(Object objs : list1) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(objs));
}`

valueOf is an String method which helps to convert primitive data types to String.

Comment: it doesnt work i get the same [Ljava.lang.Object;@60a19573, [Ljava.lang.Object;@44a085e5]